# woocommerce bookings cart not clearing

Tags: php, woocommerce

We’ve had a few store owners in the WooCommerce Bookings space reach out to us about booking slots being blocked on the calendar due to inactive carts not clearing. This meant other customers were unable to book slots that should be available.

My Page is a system that allows only 1 reservation per block.
But if the user has 1 block in the cart
Other users do not see the block.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();}
```

I tried using the code, but on the page it looks like the shopping cart is empty.
The background wc_bookings cart continues to accumulate reservations.
And the block will disappear and reservation will be impossible.
Do you have a good solution?

I am very beginner and stupid.
I don't know where to apply what, please kindly let me know